# Expanding ZFS on MDRaid?

Tags: linux, zfs, mdraid

I had a 4-disk mdraid of 8.12TB with zfsonlinux's ZFS:

```
# zpool status
  pool: tank
 state: ONLINE
  scan: none requested
config:

    NAME                  STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
    tank                  ONLINE       0     0     0
      md-name-ubuntu:md2  ONLINE       0     0     0
```

To which I added two more disks:

```
# mdadm --add /dev/md2 /dev/sde /dev/sdf
# mdadm --grow /dev/md2 -n 6
```

This finished successfully:

```
# mdadm --detail /dev/md2
/dev/md2:
        Version : 1.2
  Creation Time : Thu Jan 16 01:53:23 2014
     Raid Level : raid5
     Array Size : 14597903360 (13921.65 GiB 14948.25 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 2919580672 (2784.33 GiB 2989.65 GB)
   Raid Devices : 6
  Total Devices : 6
    Persistence : Superblock is persistent
```

During resizing, the ZFS was unmounted but not exported. It still reports its old size:

```
# zpool list
NAME   SIZE  ALLOC   FREE    CAP  DEDUP  HEALTH  ALTROOT
tank  8.12T  7.78T   349G    95%  1.04x  ONLINE  -
```

Now I tried each of these steps to expand it, all of which somebody somewhere claimed would work:

```
# zpool set autoexpand=on
# zpool export tank
# zpool import tank
```

Did nothing.

```
# zpool export tank
# zpool import -o autoexpand=on tank
```

Did nothing.

```
# zpool export tank
# zpool import -o expand=on tank
```

Did nothing.

```
# zpool online -e tank md-name-ubuntu:md2
```

Did nothing. It's not a problem with the weird name either, I also tried

```
# zpool export tank
# zpool import -d /dev/ tank
# zpool online -e tank md2
```

Except, a few minutes later as I'm writing this post, the partition table seems to have been updated (no idea which of the commands I tried caused this)

```
# gdisk -l /dev/md2
Found valid GPT with protective MBR; using GPT.
Disk /dev/md2: 29195806720 sectors, 13.6 TiB

Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
   1            2048     29195788287   13.6 TiB    BF01  zfs
   9     29195788288     29195804671   8.0 MiB     BF07
```

Still no change here though:

```
# zpool list
NAME   SIZE  ALLOC   FREE    CAP  DEDUP  HEALTH  ALTROOT
tank  8.12T  7.78T   349G    95%  1.04x  ONLINE  -
```

Does the resizing take a while? I can't see anything reporting an ongoing operation.

The relevant [zfsonlinux issue](https://github.com/zfsonlinux/zfs/issues/120) has been resolved two years ago (notice the comment claiming two of the methods I failed with here worked).

Using `zfsutils zfs-dkms Version: 0.6.2-1~saucy`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to either unload the ZFS module and reinsert it *or* just reboot.

Following that, you can run `zpool online -e devicename` and see the new zpool size.

However, I should add that I often use [ZFS atop hardware RAID](https://serverfault.com/a/545261/13325)... But using it on top of MD software RAID doesn't make much sense unless you have some other constraints.

Comment: I would have used raidz, if it had allowed me to resize the array...

Comment: so: `zpool export; modprobe -r zfs; modprobe zfs; zpool import; zpool online -e tank md2` didn't change anything either

Comment: Reboot your system.