# Dell H730 in HBA mode - Why are there issues with performance and SMART data?

Tags: raid, zfs, dell-poweredge, dell-perc, hba

I recently purchased a Dell R730xd that came with an `H730` RAID card. I would like to bring an existing 6 disk ZFS pool to this server as well as create an additional 6 disk hardware RAID.

In my research, I have read that the `H730` DOES support HBA mode. However, there are some common issues with it. Namely:

1) Performance in HBA mode is around 30% when compared to RAID mode.

2) SMART data for the underlying disks is only *sometimes* passed on to the OS.

Why do these limitations occur when using HBA mode? Do these limitations still exist when using an LSI card in HBA mode?

Comment: I replied to both questions [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/1013095/dell-r730xd-best-way-to-configure-storage-for-simultaneous-use-with-zfs-hard) (where you originally put them).

Comment: Thanks @shodanshok, I wasn't sure if I should lump them into the same post or not. I figured they were distinct enough to warrant their own posts given a user may know the answer to one but not both topics. Looks like you knew both though. Sorry if I confused by with my editing and splitting the question into two posts after you read the original!

Thanks again!